# Changing a tuple list so that the first entry is the same as the second entry

Tags: python, django

I have an example country tuple list:

`[("GB", "Great Britain"), ("IR", "Ireland"), ("IC", "Iceland")]`

For the sake of my task, I do not need the country code, only the human readable value. However Django accepts tuples in it's choiceField as such. I wrote a simple method to create a new tuple that will just contain the friendly name as both values in the tuples, e.g :

`[("Great Britain", "Great Britain"), ("Ireland", "Ireland"), ("Iceland", "Iceland")]`

But i'm looking to see if there is an easier way to do this in Django or python in comparison to my implementation. Anyone have any ideas?

**Method**

```
def change_country_tuples(country_list):
    new_country_list = []
    for country in country_list: 
        new_country_list.append(tuple((country[1], country[1])))
    return new_country_list
```

**Django choice field call**

```
country = fields.ChoiceField(
    label='Choose country',
    choices=[('', 'Select a country')] + change_country_tuples(country_choices),
)
```

**EDIT**
for clarity, updated code is:

```
def change_country_tuples(country_list):
    return [(country_name, country_name) for country_code, country_name in country_list]
```

Comment: I don't think there is simpler method per se, although you could simplify few things in the code itself, e.g. use list comprehension and drop redundant `tuple(...)`, e.g.: `return [(name, name) for code, name in country_list]`

Comment: makes sense, will update it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in python changeCountryTuples can be done in a one liner as:

`newCountryList = [(country[1],country[1]) for country in country_list]`